# Compare different forms of general solutions of a trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

What is the proper way to compare two forms of general solution of a trigonometric equation?

For example, consider the equation $(1+\cot x)^2=\mathrm{cosec}^2 x$,
$$
(1+\cot x)^2=\mathrm{cosec}^2 x\implies1+\cot^2x+2\cot x=\mathrm{cosec}^2x\\\implies\cot x=0=\cot(\pi/2)
$$
So the general solution is, $x=n\pi+\pi/2$. $\cot x=0$ also implies that $\cos x=0$, i.e
$$
\cot x=0\implies \cos x=0=\cos (\pi/2)
$$
general solution is, $x=2n\pi\pm\pi/2$

How do I compare the two results, wihout comparing both the results by substituting for $n$ ?

Comment: First of all $x=n\pi+\pi/2$ is not a correct solution. Put $n=1$ and you'll realize why. You have squared the original equation and hence are finding extra roots. Squaring also gives you extra roots of $LHS = - RHS$ in addition to $LHS=RHS$.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre: I don't see a squaring of the original equation. I see an original equation with squares.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Check out the edit history.

Comment: @dxiv: my downvote to the OP for not mentioning.

Comment: @dxiv - Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

(*Answering the question about comparing forms, not the given example which is erroneous*.)

The two representations have periods of $\pi$ and $2 \pi$. The least common multiple is $2 \pi$. For $x \in [0,2 \pi]$ both forms give the same solution set $\{\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2}\}$. Then, by periodicity, the two forms are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid squaring as here it includes  $1+\cot x=-\csc x$ as well

Use **method**$\#1:$  $\csc x-\cot x=1\iff\csc x+\cot x=1$

$$\implies\csc x=1,\cot x=0$$

So, $x$ must lie in  $(0,\pi)\pmod{2\pi}$

**method**$\#2:$

$$1=\csc x-\cot x=\cdots=\tan\dfrac x2$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $2/\pi$, you compare $2n+1$, i.e. all odd numbers, to $4n\pm1$. Modulo $4$, the $gcd$ of the coefficients of $n$, this yields the possible remainders $1$ or $3$ in both cases.